# Update a dataframe using a loop with two variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm relatively new to R and want to develop a loop that will allow me to update columns in a dataframe using two variables.

I have two main dataframes - BaseData and CountyFile (both samples - main file is approx 3m rows).

BaseData is a list of Origins and Destinations where the variable (1,2,3,4 etc) represents the id for the County. So, for UserID 2 the origin is County 1 and Destination is County 2 and so on.

```
BaseData
     UserID Origin Destination
1       1      1           1
2       2      2           1
3       3      3           2
4       4      4           4
5       5      1           2
6       6      1           3
```

CountyFile is a dataframe that will contain a sum of all of the interactions between the Destination county (County_ID) and all Origin counties (C_1, C_2 etc).

```
CountyFile    
     CountyID C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4 C_5 C_6 C_7
 1         1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 2         2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 3         3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 4         4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 5         5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 6         6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I can get the required information by creating a subset of BaseData (where Destination == 1), group and sum the Origins and then update CountyFile.C_1.

```
Temp1 <- subset(BaseData, Destination  == 1) 
Temp2 <- as.data.frame(table(Temp1$Origin))
CountyFile$C_1<-Temp2[match(CountyFile$CountyID, Temp2$Var1),2]
```

This updates my CountyFile dataframe for the first Destination selection (see below). I would like to use a loop to run through all Destinations (01 to 15) rather than doing this manually.

```
    CountyID C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4 C_5 C_6 C_7
1         1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
2         2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
3         3  NA   0   0   0   0   0   0
4         4  NA   0   0   0   0   0   0
5         5  NA   0   0   0   0   0   0
6         6   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

I've made some effort using a nested loop and two variables (i and j) below but to no avail. Perhaps someone could provide a much easier solution?

```
for (i in c(01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15)) 
{
Temp1 <- subset(BaseData, Destination  == i) 
Temp2 <- as.data.frame(table(Temp1$Origin)) }
for (j in c("C_1","C_2","C_3","C_4","C_5","C_6","C_7")) 
{
CountyFile$j<-Temp2[match(CountyFile$CountyID, Temp2$Var1),2]
}
```

Thanks

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are much simpler ways to manipulate data in R. Here is one way to do using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
# the actual code starts
setDT(BaseData)
# count the number of rows in each Destination, Origin combinations
CountData <- BaseData[, .N, by = .(Destination, Origin)]
# reshape the data
OutputData <- dcast(CountData, Destination ~ Origin)
# rename the columns
names(OutputData) <- c("CountyID", 
                       paste0("C_", 1:7))
```

I used this example data

```
# generate example data
N <- 500
BaseData <- data.frame(UserId = seq(N),
                       Destination = sample(15, N, TRUE),
                       Origin = sample(7, N, TRUE))
```

The output looks like this:

```
head(OutputData)
##    CountyID C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4 C_5 C_6 C_7
## 1:        1   1   1   5   5   5   7   7
## 2:        2  10   4   6   4   3   8   3
## 3:        3   5   4   6   3   4   6   6
## 4:        4   9   4   1   3   2   5   4
## 5:        5   7   2  10   8   4   1   7
## 6:        6   6   5   4   4   4   6   5
```

Comment: Fantastic. This solution worked perfectly. Thank you for your assistance!